# Rails: Prevent duplicate entry from simultaneous submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, queue, duplicates

We're having a problem with our app allowing people to sign up multiple times with the same account information (email, specifically).

Our user model validates the uniqueness of the email parameter, and we are also using some javascript to make sure that once the "sign up" button is clicked, it becomes unusable unless the sign up fails (theoretically ensuring only a single click).

It *appears* that the problem stems from users double-clicking the signup button *before* the javascript on the page finishes loading.

Is there a way from the Rails side that we can prevent this?  Maybe something that creates a request stack, and then iterates through them?  I ask because we can't be the only site that has this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dumb question: Why don't you set the field in the database itself to unique?

If that is not possible, do what Steve Bourne suggested and use something like this:

```
var clicked = false;
$('#submit_button').click( function() {
  $(this).preventDefault();
  if(!clicked) {
    clicked = true;
    $('#submit_button').attr('disabled','disabled');
    $('#form').submit();
}
```

Now, I didn't test that so setting `clicked = true` may be overkill ;)

Comment: Yeah, I think we're going to force uniqueness in the database itself, so hopefully it will prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Set the text field to Nothing right after the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely convinced that's what's happening, but another option would be to only enable the submit button in jQuery's ready function, and start off with it hidden or disabled. Are you running a large amount of JS outside of the ready function?

Comment: Yeah, we have quite a heavy JS file that loads in outside of the ready function.

Comment: Ah; unfortunate ;) I'd probably keep it disabled until it's ready to go then.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that users submit the form before your javascript is finished loading, why not make that impossible?  (i.e. the submit button action doesn't submit the form, but your javascript submits on the click event?)

There are a few ways to then prevent dupes in JS; sounds like you've got that covered already.